# Missing Count attribute In Modelviewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using `Modelviewsets` and everything is working fine expect there is no count parameter in response. I suspect may be pagination not working but I have defined pagination in DRF settings

**settings :**

```
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGINATE_BY': 100,                 # Default to 10
'PAGINATE_BY_PARAM': 'page_size',  # Allow client to override, using `?page_size=xxx`.
'MAX_PAGINATE_BY': 10             # Maximum limit allowed when using `?page_size=xxx`.
```

**views :**

```
class VenueViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Manage CRUD on venues here
    """
    queryset = Venue.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.VenueSerializer
    filter_backends = (ModifiedFilterBackend,)
    paginate_by = settings.VENUES_PAGINATION
```

**Response :**

```
[
  {
    "id": 54,
    "name": "v1",
    "description": "dfqw",
    "address": {
      "city": {
        "name": "abc",
        "state": {
          "name": "PO",
          "code": "MK"
        },
        "country": {
          "name": "XYZ",
          "code": "XY"
        },
        "id": 22
      },
      "address_line_1": "abcd",
      "address_line_2": "qwert",
      "zip_code": 123654,
      "place_id": null
    },
    "is_deleted": false,
    "parent": null
  }
]
```

Comment: I think problem probably because you are setting `paginate_by = settings.VENUES_PAGINATION` explicitly

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev even if I commented this part, No sucess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `PAGE_SIZE` setting. Please refer [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#setting-the-pagination-style).

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

Comment: not working , however I just pasted class setting here but I have defined other settings too. Updated my question

Comment: What is your `django rest framework` version? Because `PAGINATE_BY` is removed in the latest version. [reference](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#default_filter_backends). Instead of that now you can use `PAGE_SIZE`

Comment: Yes it was rest version issue. On Production rest version was 3.2 and on local it was 3.4 . Iwas confused by it is working on production but not local. Thx a lot